# Bind arguments to function with bash

Tags: javascript, bash, shell

Using JavaScript we can do something like this:

```
const foo = function(a,b,c){
  console.log(Array.from(arguments));
};

const bar = foo.bind(null,'this is 1');
bar(2,3);
```

we will get this output:

```
[ 'this is 1', 2, 3 ]
```

is there a way to do this kind of thing with bash somehow?

I am trying to store/export a reference to arguments. However, I read that with bash you can't export an array e.g. `declare -a arr=()`...is there some way to store arguments so that you can use them again later, for example retry functionality?

Perhaps something like this:

```
export some_val=1;

outer(){

   local v="$some_val"

   inner(){
      echo "$v" "$@"
   }

   export -f inner;
}
```

then it would be like:

```
outer
inner '2' '3'
```

that bash technique doesn't work for more than one reason - one - you are stuck with only one definition of inner because the new def will overwrite the old one...but more importantly it doesn't remember the local value of v if you call it after calling outer.

Comment: When you say "use later", do you mean later within the same script, or in a different script / process?

Comment: `export` is for passing environment variables to child processes, I don't see why you would need to do that with an array.

Comment: Can you show what the script is like that would need this function?

Comment: The reason I ask the question is because I cannot call `export array=( foo bar baz )` because arrays cannot be stored like that, right? The only way to store args would be like `declare -a arr=( "$@" )`, but I cannot export that.

Comment: Functions run in the same shell process as the rest of the script, you don't need to export a variable for the function to use it.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create a closure, `bash` doesn't have that.

Comment: `inner` can't be used from outside `outer`. `export` doesn't change that.

Comment: `inner` is a global name, like any other name defined inside a function, except there is no way (that I know of) to mark a function name as local.

Comment: `local inner(){}`? lulz idk maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` doesn't have sophisticated lexical scoping, and it doesn't have closures. You have to emulate what you want using global variables.

You can use an array to hold multiple values. Since the functions all run in the same shell process, you don't need to export it.

```
declare -a v

outer() {
    v=("$@")
}

inner() {
    echo "${v[@]}" "$@"
}

outer 1
inner 2 3 # prints 1 2 3
outer 15 16 17
inner 5 6 # prints 15 16 17 5 6
```